# Subset df using unique timestamps - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to return rows associated with the first two unique timestamps only in a df. However, with below, I'm returning the first two of every timestamp.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({  
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.100','2019-08-02 09:50:10.100','2019-08-02 09:50:10.100','2019-08-02 09:50:10.200','2019-08-02 09:50:10.200','2019-08-02 09:50:10.200','2019-08-02 09:50:10.300','2019-08-02 09:50:10.300','2019-08-02 09:50:10.300'],                                     
        })

df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])

df1 = df1.groupby(['Time']).head(2)
```

intended:

```
                     Time
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering by [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-ngroup) less than 2:

```
new_df = df1[df1.groupby('Time').ngroup().lt(2)]
```

`new_df`:

```
                     Time
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
4 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
5 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
```

`groupby ngroup` creates group numbers for each Time:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
dtype: int64
```

Then select only rows associated with the 0th and 1st times. (`lt 2`) or (`le 1`)

---

Or with [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas-series-unique) to get unique time values slice off the first 2, then use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin) to test time values:

```
new_df = df1[df1['Time'].isin(df1['Time'].unique()[:2])]
```

`new_df`:

```
                     Time
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
4 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
5 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
```